# How to call the value of a function-pointer member of a nested class of some enclosing class from within another nested class?

Tags: c++, pointers, encapsulation, member, pointer-to-member

This is a pretty convoluted question, but I've tried to simplify the code as much as possible from my actual codebase. Let's say I have some class `T` with nested classes `S` and `M`. I have some methods `method1` and `method2` of `S`, and I also have a pointer `selectedMethod` that points to one selected of the two methods, by default `method1`.

```
class T
{
    class S
    {
        T &t;

        double method1(std::vector <double> params);
        double method2(std::vector <double> params);

        double (S::*selectedMethod)(std::vector <double>) = &S::method1;
    }

    class M
    {
        T &t;

        double method3(std::vector <double> vec);
    }

    S s;
    M m;
}
```

As shown, I store the instance of `T` that the instances of `S` and `M`, `s` and `m` respectively, correspond to using the pointers `t`.

Next, let's say that I'd like to call whichever method `selectedMethod` points to within some method `method3` of `M`. Why is it that this has to be done with:

```
double T::M::method3(std::vector <double> vec){

    double ret = (&t.s->*t.s.selectedMethod)(vec);

    return ret;
}
```

instead of simply

```
double T::M::method3(std::vector <double> vec){

    double ret = (*t.s.selectedMethod)(vec);

    return ret;
}
```

? To me the prefix `&t.s->` seems redundant.

Comment: Well, here one of the t.s should not be required, but it depends, how this is connected. In general, the fact, that a class in nested is not related to its instance. These classes could not be nested and still you will use the same code. Only T::M will be just M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To me the prefix `&t.s->` seems redundant

It only seems that way because you store the pointer to member inside the same object on which you invoke the member. But given the general case

```
auto foo_ptr = &SomeClass::foo;
SomeClass obj;

(obj*.foo_ptr)();
```

Both parts of the syntax are required. One obviously denotes the member, while the other denotes that *object* that is being accessed.

In your special case the object may "appear" twice, but the two ends of the expression still denote different things. On the right hand side `t.s.selectedMethod` still only designates the pointer. The compiler is not obliged to examine the expression and divine the object from it.